# nginx server : cannot connect 128.0.0.1:8888

Tags: django, nginx

My error

Unable to connect
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8888.

ls -l /etc/fdfs/
total 84

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1469 六月 14 10:10 client.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1461 六月 14 09:44 client.conf.sample
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   955 六月 14 14:31 http.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 31172 六月 14 14:31 mime.types
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3725 六月 14 14:22 mod_fastdfs.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7938 六月 14 10:02 storage.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7927 六月 14 09:44 storage.conf.sample
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   105 六月 14 09:44 storage_ids.conf.sample
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7394 六月 14 10:25 tracker.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7389 六月 14 09:44 tracker.conf.sample
```

my server 
ps aux |grep nginx

```
root      29867  0.0  0.0  38152   616 ?        Ss   14:41   0:00 nginx: master process ./nginx
coco      30010  0.0  0.0  21532  1084 pts/2    S+   14:55   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

/usr/local/nginx/conf

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
            listen       8888;
            server_name  localhost;
            location ~/group[0-9]/ {
                ngx_fastdfs_module;
            }
            error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
            }
    }
```

I am trying to view picture that I just upload .
Command like this

```
fdfs_upload_file /etc/fdfs/client.conf /home/coco/Pictures/coco.jpg 
group1/M00/00/00/wKgTgF7lxkyAGO0-AAAiaSlNP3Q922.jpg
```

Comment: your server name is localhost so the address must be http://localhost:8888

Comment: I have a try with localhost:8888 ,but still unable to connect .Tks anyway

Comment: if you want to view media files you have to make settings for media and media_root in settings.py after that in development mode check settings for static development.

Comment: Got it .I am try to setup the environment. I need to make sure it's work in terminal .Then I will setup in Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I double check my tracker.conf and I find I forget change bath_path 
It should be

```
base_path=/home/coco/fastdfs/tracker/
```

After change my server process like this

```
root      31082  0.0  0.2 141252  6804 ?        Ss   15:28   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data  31546  0.0  0.2 143924  6464 ?        S    15:36   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  31547  0.0  0.2 143924  6464 ?        S    15:36   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      31678  0.0  0.0  38156   616 ?        Ss   15:45   0:00 nginx: master process ./nginx
nobody    31679  0.0  0.1  43096  4184 ?        S    15:45   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      31712  0.0  0.0  21532  1056 pts/3    S+   15:47   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuTJV.png)

It's work